# Doctrine migration: adding and removing two foreign key columns to existing table is not working

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have the existing table `pricing`, on migration script I would like to add two new columns `pricing_set_id` and `coe_id` which both are foreign keys.

On `up` function, it runs perfectly without any errors, but when I run `down` function, it got the errors. My code as below.

On `up` function:

```
$pricingTable = $schema->getTable('pricing');
$pricingSetTable = $schema->getTable('pricing_set');

if (!$pricingTable->hasColumn('pricing_set_id')) {
    $pricingTable->addColumn('pricing_set_id', 'uuid')->setNotnull(false);
}

if (!$pricingTable->hasIndex('FK_pricing_set_idx')) {
    $pricingTable->addIndex(['pricing_set_id'], 'FK_pricing_set_idx');
}

if (!$pricingTable->hasForeignKey('FK_pricing_set')) {
    $pricingTable->addForeignKeyConstraint($pricingSetTable,
        ['pricing_set_id'],
        ['id'],
        ['onUpdate' => 'CASCADE', 'onDelete' => 'CASCADE'],
        'FK_pricing_set');
}

if (!$pricingTable->hasColumn('coe_id')) {
    $pricingTable->addColumn('coe_id', 'uuid')->setNotnull(false);
}

if (!$pricingTable->hasIndex('FK_pricing_coe_idx')) {
    $pricingTable->addIndex(['coe_id'], 'FK_pricing_coe_idx');
}

if (!$pricingTable->hasForeignKey('FK_pricing_coe')) {
    $pricingTable->addForeignKeyConstraint($schema->getTable('user'),
        ['coe_id'],
        ['id'],
        ['onUpdate' => 'CASCADE','onDelete' => 'CASCADE'], 
        'FK_pricing_coe');    
}
```

On `down` function:

```
$pricingTable = $schema->getTable('pricing');

if ($pricingTable->hasForeignKey('FK_pricing_set')) {
    $pricingTable->removeForeignKey('FK_pricing_set');
}

if ($pricingTable->hasColumn('pricing_set_id')) {
    $pricingTable->dropColumn('pricing_set_id');
}

if ($pricingTable->hasIndex('FK_pricing_set_idx')) {
    $pricingTable->dropIndex('FK_pricing_set_idx');
}

if ($pricingTable->hasForeignKey('FK_pricing_coe')) {
    $pricingTable->removeForeignKey('FK_pricing_coe');
}

if ($pricingTable->hasColumn('coe_id')) {
    $pricingTable->dropColumn('coe_id');
}

if ($pricingTable->hasIndex('FK_pricing_coe_idx')) {
    $pricingTable->dropIndex('FK_pricing_coe_idx');
}
```

The error I got:

```
 -> ALTER TABLE pricing DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_pricing_set
 -> DROP INDEX FK_pricing_set_idx ON pricing
 -> DROP INDEX FK_pricing_coe_idx ON pricing
```

> Migration 20141031071812 failed during Execution. Error An exception occurred while executing 'DROP INDEX FK_pricing_coe_idx ON pricing':
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'FK_pricing_coe_idx': needed in a foreign key constraint.

I have noticed the order of SQL which Doctrine generates is not exactly the same as expected on Doctrine code. It removes the index `FK_pricing_coe_idx` without removing its foreign key. this might be the reason why it got error.

is there any way to work around for this thing?

Comment: Which doctrine version are you using? More importantly, which version of doctrine was used to generate the migration?

Comment: @nem75: Sorry for late reply, we use Symfony 2.4, it means Doctrine version around 2.2

Comment: Judging from this issue https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/issues/83 I suspect Doctrine 2.2 could exhibit the behavior you describe. Possibly even 2.3. Updating to the latest Doctrine version (and then regenerating the migrations) or editing the migration manually are probably your best options.

Comment: I doesn't work to separate the second drop in another migration? Probably not ideal but might work.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because the FK_pricing_coe foreign key still exists when the index is getting removed.